# sequelize do not include junction table in associated model data

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Lets say I have 2 models, User and Event. They are set up as a m:m relationship `User.belongsToMany(Event)` and `Event.belongsToMany(User)`. This all works fine, but when I do `User.findAndCountAll({include: [{model: Event}]})`, the resulting json for result.rows looks like

```
[
    ...
    {
        userdata...,
        events: [ // included by model relation
        ...included event data...,
        junction_table: { // I dont want this data sent back to client, just above data
            ...data i dont want...
        }
    }
...
]
```

I want

```
[
    {
    userdata...,
    events: [
        { included event data without junction_table }
    ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to strip out the junction_table that for some reason is automatically included with every single event without .mapping over the data and rebuilding it? I'd rather not send all this data I don't need over the wire to the clients all the time. I tried only specifying `attributes: []` on the model, but it won't go away.

Comment: currently my working solution is to convert the sequelize results to POJO by `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sequelizeresults.rows))` and mapping over them to delete the junction_table property from each event before sending to client.

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by specifying that you don't want the "through" table attributes, according to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961046/sequelize-returns-join-table-in-query).

In your case, it would be :

```
User.findAndCountAll({
    include: 
        [{model: Event, through: { attributes: [] }}]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b ON EXISTS
        ( SELECT * FROM junction j
        WHERE j.a_id = a.a_id
        AND j.b_id = b.b_id
        );
```

---

This only works if the junction table is unique on `{a_id , b_id}`
, with `a_id` , `b_id` being the primary keys of `a` and `b`.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question. The joins via sequelize model relations are working properly. The problem is `b` automatically includes a property with the data from the junction table, which I do not want to be included in the result set in order to save on data transfer.

Comment: Well, this is a way to do this join_without_the_columns_from_the_junction_table_in the_result_set in plain SQL. Maybe you can find a way for your framework to generate similar code.