# Sequelize returns join table in query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've got a many-to-many relation in my MSQL table between these two model:

> - Venue - Representing a venue which can have multiple owners (employees)
> - Employee - Representing an employee which can be either a ceo or sales employee or whatsoever.

*I am using [sequelize](/questions/tagged/sequelize) to set up the relations like so:*

#### Relation Employee > Venue

```
 Employee.associate = function (models) { 
   models.Employee.belongsToMany(models.Venue, { through: 'EmployeeVenues' })
 }
```

#### Relation Venue > Employee

```
 Venue.associate = function (models) {
    models.Venue.belongsToMany(models.Employee, { through: 'EmployeeVenues' })
 }
```

#### Sequelize docs

> According to the [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html) it will create a new model called EmployeeVenues with the equivalent foreign keys employee_id and venue_id. Defining through is required. Sequelize would previously attempt to autogenerate names but that would not always lead to the most logical setups. This will add methods **getVenues**, setVenues, addVenue, addUsers to Employee.

---

And this is correctly working, when I fire up my Sequelize it creates a new table called EmpoyeeVenues with the correct foreign keys as a compound key. However when I query getVenues it does not return the expected output. Instead, it's returning the associated table values as well, which I don't want.

---

#### Query to get all venues belonging to an employee with id equal 1

---

```
router.get('/api/v1/users/:employee_id/venues', (request, response) => {
  var employeeId = request.params.employee_id;

  models.Employee.findOne({
    where: {id: employeeId}
  }).then((employee) => {

    if(!employee) { return response.status(400).send("Employee doesnt have a venue registered yet.")}
    var venues = employee.getVenues().then((venues) => {
    response.status(200).send(venues);
  })
})
});
```

#### Response Result

---

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "capacity": "11",
        "venue_name": "Club Fix",
        "venue_description": "Club in Tilburg",
        "EmployeeVenues": {
            "employee_id": 1,
            "venue_id": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "capacity": "400",
        "venue_name": "Club Vie",
        "venue_description": "Club in Rotterdam",
        "EmployeeVenues": {
            "employee_id": 1,
            "venue_id": 2
        }
    }
]
```

#### Question

> Why is EmployeeVenues included in this query provided by Sequelize? And How can I prevent EmployeeVenues to be included in the response?

## Update

> According to a issue on the Sequelize github page which was made in 2014 there is a solution that works

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2143

```
    User.find({
    where: {id: userId}, attributes: userFields,
    include: [
      {model: db.Role, attributes: roleFields, through: {attributes: []}}
    ]
});
```

---

But it does not match the documented version in the Sequelize documentation which is up-to-date, at least it should be.

---

```
User.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Project,
    through: {
      attributes: ['createdAt', 'startedAt', 'finishedAt'],
      where: {completed: true}
    }
  }]
});
```

---

Or even simple stated on the [reference documentation:](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html)

---

```
user.getPictures() // gets you all pictures
```

Answer (score 10):

## Update

> According to a issue on the Sequelize github page which was made in 2014 there is a solution that works

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2143

```
    User.find({
    where: {id: userId}, attributes: userFields,
    include: [
      {model: db.Role, attributes: roleFields, through: {attributes: []}}
    ]
});
```

---

But it does not match the documented version in the Sequelize documentation which is up-to-date, at least it should be.

---

```
User.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Project,
    through: {
      attributes: ['createdAt', 'startedAt', 'finishedAt'],
      where: {completed: true}
    }
  }]
});
```

---

Or even simple stated on the [reference documentation:](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html)

---

```
user.getPictures() // gets you all pictures
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer given lefts out an important thing that's needed- where to keep the attributes which are need from the included model, here - Project. The [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2143) on github has final answer but still not the complete answer which I was looking forward to.

We need to re-specify the attributes at the model level and then make the join table attributes as none

```
User.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Project,

    through: 'JoinTableAliasName' /// only if exist/needed
    as: 'modelAssociationAlias' // only if exist/needed

    // attributes needed from Project table
    attributes: ['createdAt', 'startedAt', 'finishedAt'],

    through: { // through again doesn't create any issue
      attributes: [], // this helps removing the join table in returned data
      where: {completed: true}
    }
  }]
});
```

Comment: I struggled to find a good illustration of this. While it wasn't quite what I was doing, it gave me enough to figure out what I needed to do (so thanks for the extra comments).

Comment: If you want to specify through table attributes using association mixins, you will need to pass {joinTableAttributes: ['fields']} inside mixin method.

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked perfectly in my case:

```
user.getPictures({joinTableAttributes: []})
```

[Foo.belongsToMany](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#foobelongstomanybar--through-baz-)